# UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this error? I've not ever seen it before.
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 17 errors
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x002da] in <42a64fd733d9417da1ea3a757ad9a96d>:0
at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (System.Boolean askForBuildLocation, UnityEditor.BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x00080] in <42a64fd733d9417da1ea3a757ad9a96d>:0
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

I don't know what to try for it as I've never seen this error before.

Comment: The important details for what failed are in one of the other two errors you don't have highlighted in your screenshot or the editor.log file.

Comment: I've edited it to show more information